# Sending HTTP 404 response causes browser to wait indefinitely

Tags: http, http-status-code-404

I developed my own HTTP server in Python and it works perfectly until I send a null page with 404 page not found header.  The browser receiving the null page displays the 404 page and then goes into a wait loop indefinitely.  Do I need to close the connection to the client to get the browser to stop waiting?

Comment: On which browser/versions is this happening?  Typically a 404 error is not something the client would be recovering from without manual intervention anyway.

Comment: Please add code and make it [mcve]

Comment: Please indicate which headers you are sending to the browser.

Comment: After further investigation (and some trial and error!), I determined that the cause of the problem was the lack of a "Content-Length" pragma in then header and that there was no HTML document associated with the page.  I added a 'Content-Length' pragma and an empty document (just <body></body>) and it works correctly every time!!  The lesson here is that, if you are sending a response to a GET request, you must have a document along with the header.

I thank all of you who responded.